# How do I remove a password from FileVault?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, filevault

Before installing Mac OS X Yosemite, I created an encrypted partition and provided it with a password. When the installation finished I created a user and that user is in sync with FileVault, its password can unlock the file system, but so does the other password.

How do I remove that other password?

The symptom right now is what when the computer starts it displays this:

[image]

and the [Update Needed] entry allows me to decrypt the FileVault volume with the very simple password I set when installing this machine.

Comment: It [seems that there's a similar problem and solution here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157859) *you have to disable FileVault on your main partition, which is named "Macintosh HD" by default, and reboot afterwards. When the boot process has picked up your user name and picture, you can re-enable FileVault again*. Did you tried?

Comment: Well, of course disabling and re-enabling FileVault would fix it, as that's the source of the problem; but I wanted to achieve this without increasing insecurity. The reason why this volume is encrypted is because I encrypted before installing and copying the data to avoid having data unencrypted at any point. We ended up turning it off and on again. I bet it is possible, but I can't find how.

Comment: Following Soliton on this site [Jul 25, 2012 8:43 PM](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?tstart=0) he said  _repaired disk permissions with Disk Utility, re-downloaded and re-installed [Java manually from Apple's web site] (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515) and re-selected my user login photo and re-typed my user name (for good measure). After rebooting, everything is back to normal_. Just Tried this  approach? It seems [interesting this too] (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61090/what-does-update-needed-mean-when-attempting-to-boot-from-an-encrypted-backu)

Comment: Try to reset password. In the [same post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?start=15&tstart=0)  InsuranceITGuy
at Sep 6, 2013 10:58 AM say how to change the password, via `    diskutil cs list` and after `diskutil cs changeVolumePassphrase <UUID>`. Maybe can be a good approach too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not a new problem. Those are some of the solutions where declared effective on internet.

- **Change the user password** strategy
  *"...we were able to get rid of the "Update Needed" by changing the user's password. When the user rebooted the "Update Needed" was gone and the user's name was back where it used to be"*
  by GreggNIHDMS Sep 20, 2013 11:38 AM [From here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?start=15&tstart=0)
- *"**diskutil cs**"* approach (without a recovery key and decrypt/encrypt all the HDD):
   *Typing that command in a terminal window displayed a full list of usage commands, and among them was "changeVolumePassphrase".*

  - `diskutil cs list` from terminal windows, logged on as an administrative user
  - Select the needed UUID in the terminal window (and copy it to the clipboard)
  - `diskutil cs changeVolumePassphrase 9F203449-4173-49F9-B62E-C6276A29AC69` (put your UUID)
  - It should prompt for the old passphrase and the new passphrase.  After a few short moments of work and a few new lines of output, it should confirm by saying "Finished CoreStorage operation".
  - Reboot
    InsuranceITGuy Sep 6, 2013 10:58 AM [from this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?start=15&tstart=0) 
    I immediately rebooted, and was greeted by a beautiful sight - the disk icon and "Disk Password" text above the password field.
- **Disk Utility approach**  (maybe the same?)
  *"I just repaired disk permissions with **Disk Utility**, re-downloaded and re-installed Java manually from [Apple's web site](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515) and re-selected my user login photo and re-typed my user name (for good measure). After rebooting, everything is back to normal"*
  *soliton* Jul 25, 2012 8:43 PM from [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3321886?tstart=0) and maybe with more explanation Adam Masri
  Jan 18, 2015 3:00 PM from the same post.
- **A Reset the *FireValut*** strategy:

  - Log in into the Mac as administrator.
  - Backup the Mac with Time Machine (optional but recommended)
  - Launch System Preferences selecting System Preferences from the Apple menu.
  - Disable FileVault:
    Click the Security & Privacy preference pane.
    Click the FileVault tab.
    Unlock the pane clicking on the padlock (administrator password required)
    Disable FileVault and wait (…about 3hrs with a 250GB no SSD HD)
  - Restart the Mac (optional but recommended)
  - Enable FileVault and wait (…about 7hrs for me!!!)
    Go back the FileVault tab and enable
  - Restart the Mac.

  The unknown user account should be disappeared. 
  From different places [one for all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157159)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the FileVault2 master password, just delete:

> - /Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.keychain
> - /Library/Keychains/FileVaultMaster.cer

As with every system files, remember to back them up somewhere in case it crashes everything. You're now done removing the master password. Now, you may want to set a *new* strong password in

> System Preferences > Users & Groups > Service gear > Change Master
>   Password

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the passwords are out of sync. It's annoying.

1. Disable Filevault. It'll take a while to decrypt.
2. Update the OS. Restart. Check for updates. Etc...
3. Enable FileVault.

Or... I think...

1. Run `sudo fdesetup remove -user <username>`
2. Open FileVault tab under Security in Preferences.
3. Enable  for FileVault.

Comment: Were you able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to disable and re-enable FileVault 2 to modify any of its settings. As long as you can unlock a FileVault encrypted volume (i.e., you have access to a personal or institutional recovery key or simply the password of a FileVault-enabled user), you can modify FileVault 2 settings using the `fdesetup` utility.

In my case, when I first got a new computer, I immediately started it in Recovery Mode (⌘R at startup), then manually converted Mac OS X's main partition to an encrypted volume using the `diskutil coreStorage encryptVolume <logical-volume-UUID>` command from a terminal prompt. This resulted in a FileVault 2 pre-boot login window that created a "Disk Passphrase" user icon (because I had not yet created any actual user accounts in Mac OS X). After creating my actual user accounts, I wanted to remove this temporary password I had assigned earlier. To do so, I issued the following commands from an admin user:

```
sudo fdesetup list -extended
```

This returned output like this:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo fdesetup list -extended
Password:
ESCROW  UUID                                                                     TYPE USER
        CB4118C3-8D9D-43E3-BF9E-C3EF71C3C2D6                     Disk Passphrase User
        D934966C-D556-4A25-917F-EEC109C0FFAD                                  OS User ExampleUser
        F94E6F5D-B764-968F-AAE4-0BD4E88A489F                                  OS User AdminUser
```

Notice how there were three entries listed, despite the fact that my system had only two user accounts. The following command removed the "Disk Passphrase" user icon from the FileVault pre-boot screen:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -uuid CB4118C3-8D9D-43E3-BF9E-C3EF71C3C2D6
```

Of course, UUID value will probably be different on your machine. You can use the `fdesetup remove` command to remove any listed entry, not just a Disk Passphrase one.

See `man fdesetup` for details.

Creating an encrypted volume *before* writing any personal data to it is the recommended way to provide maximum security for your data at rest. As the OP mentioned, the whole point of using FileVault is to ensure that at no point is your data written to the drive unencrypted. Thankfully, with the above command procedure, there is no need to ever disable FileVault in order to remove temporary passwords used for disk setup purposes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo fdesetup list
   Then remove 'offending' users with:
2. sudo fdesetup remove -user (where user is the name of the user listed via step 1.)
   Or, use the commands documented above by Meitar to use the uuids instead of usernames.